# Libgdx: How to calculate sprite size when viewport is in used

Tags: libgdx, viewport

I have few questions regarding using libgdx viewport.

1. I have initialised a viewport with this virtual screen size (800 x 480). I'm trying to display a sprite with (100 x 100) virtual size. Do I recalculate based on the screen size ratio to supply the size? Or I just apply virtual size directly to the sprite?
2. When I initialised a camera, I can supply virtual width and height. I also noticed that, I can supply the virtual width and height when initialising a viewport. Are these 2 different things? Or I just need to supply the virtual width and height either in viewport or camera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) If you are working with a virtual screen size, you will use virtual sizes for your sprites to draw them. If you use a `FitViewport` with 800x480 size and render a Sprite of (virtual) size 800x480 (you supply these values to the `SpriteBatch`), then it will fill the whole screen, even if the actual screen would be 1600x960.

2) A `Viewport` manages the `Camera.viewportWidth` and `camera.viewportHeight` for you, based on the strategy that you chose for the `Viewport`. You can set it yourself, but when you do `Viewport.update(...)` or `Viewport.apply()`, the values of your camera will be overridden.